# How to automatically refresh sql server olap cube

Tags: sql-server, olap-cube

I have built a cube in visual studio and deployed to SSAS. How can I get the data refreshed using a nightly sql batch job or some other means?
TIA

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

1. Put a Process Analysis Services task in an SSIS package, and schedule the package with SQL Agent (great if you already have an etl package).
2. Using SSMS, go to the Process dialog box but hit "Script" at the start to get the XMLA command. Then put this in a SQL Agent job.

Comment: Looks like I didn't install part of SSMS as I don't have option to connect to AS. Got it in VS though, but it doesn't have an option to get the script on the process dialog box.
We actually  had it setup to do a full process but it looks like I have to process each dimension first, otherwise it fails.

Comment: Graeme - you only need to process the dimensions that have changed. If processing them all really slows down the job then you can test to see which dimensions have had changes and only process those.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>CUBEOLAP</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```